# Issue with OAuth2 authentication with google spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-sheets-api, google-oauth

I am using java library for oauth2 authentication for accessing google spreadsheet.

I am using below code for OAuth2 authentication:

```
credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setTokenServerEncodedUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
    .setServiceAccountScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://docs.google.com/feeds")
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("xxxxx-privatekey.p12")).build();
```

After getting "credential", using below code to read spreadsheet:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService(
                        "MySpreadsheetIntegration");
service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");          
SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
System.out.println(feed.getTotalResults());
```

Executing above code give me back total result 0.

If I use:

```
service.setUserCredentials("email", "password");
```

in place of oauth2 authentication, it gives me back correct results. Not sure what is wrong with the OAuth2 authentication. 
Also when I print "access token" from "credential" object it prints a valid access token.

Answer (score 2):

I use:

```
spreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService("cellmaster.com.au-v0.2");  
spreadsheetService.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

rather than:

```
spreadsheetService = new SpreadsheetService("cellmaster.com.au-v0.2");  
spreadsheetService.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);
```

also I had to add code for the refresh token. As the access token soon expires. But the refresh token works as you would expect.

Comment: spreadsheetService.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); The method setHeader(String, String) is undefined for the type SpreadsheetService i am using gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar lib  can you use same version

Comment: core-1.47.1.jar looks to be the Jar file I used - https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/Service#setHeader(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) - I did have jar file issues with sending email, and so used a bit of a non standard combination.  -- But these day I use ethercalc, like google sheets but all open souce