# Google Spreadsheets API batch insert

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I make a batch insert with big data to Google Spreadsheets using API?

I found the batch request in the api, but:

> insert and delete are not supported because the cells feed cannot be
>   used to insert or delete cells.

(https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/)

Comment: what is it that you want to do? The api will let you resize the sheet, and do a batch update of the sheet. Also, why the big data comment? There is a limit of 400,000 cells per spreadsheet for gdata (they are working on expanding this to 2 million)

Comment: that's ok, but now I can insert only cell-by-cell and it's so slow!

Comment: yes, large sheets have a slow write time. For a read, write and re-read of sheet with 4000 cells it is taking about 4-8 seconds. Of the 4-8 seconds, 2.5 are for the write. It does get faster with the 2nd write, the 1st write tends to be slow. did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402733/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-lot-of-data-throug/9495293#9495293

Comment: I have a csv file with 40,000 cells and i need to paste it to spreadsheets. If I insert my data cell-by-cell every cell insert spend about 1-2 sec and over 10 hours to add all the data to document.

Comment: Use a batch insert as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402733/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-lot-of-data-throug/9495293#9495293  .... did a test, took 5 seconds to insert 4000 cells into a 40,000 cell sheet.

Comment: I'm trying do it this way, but I have the "missing resource version id" error.
Here is the source code of batch: https://gist.github.com/g0ddest/ee80100a79a2a4534cd7

Comment: I suspect you want to set SepreadsheetService like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084133/issue-with-oauth2-authentication-with-google-spreadsheet/15152682#15152682  --- There is no one example that has fast batch update and OAuth2 for the google-spreadsheet-api in Java, so many people want one. I have the bits, but not in example form.