# How to use SpreadsheetsService authenticated by ServiceAccountCredential?

Tags: .net, google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-authentication

I need to use SpreadsheetsService, but I don't find the way in the official documentation `.net`.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=ja#authorizing_requests

I have my service authenticated:

```
String serviceAccountEmail = "serviceAccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"privatekey.p12", "pass", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

From here I can instantiate almost any service.

For example Drive Service:

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
    });
```

But with `SpreadsheetsService` I can do this, because SpreadsheetsService wait for an string 'application name' in his default constructor or an GOAuth2RequestFactory in his property `RequestFactory`.

How to authenticate SpreadsheetsService with an ServiceAccountCredential?

Comment: With Java you can use: spreadsheetService.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken); But not sure about .net .... setHeader example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084133/issue-with-oauth2-authentication-with-google-spreadsheet/15152682#15152682

Comment: Did you find the answer? I am trying to do the same thing, but SpreadsheetsService supports only application name as a parameter. Is there any workaround you used? setUserCredentials works for me if I am just a regular, not a domain user.

Comment: What's _namespace and assembly_ for `DriveService` ?

Comment: This might be helpful - http://blog.antontelle.com/post/sending-data-to-private-google-spreadsheet-via-service-account

Answer (score 6):

Here is the answer on how to do this.....
The key is to use the customHeaders on a new requestFactory

```
 var certificate = new
 System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(p12KeyFileName,
 "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

 string SCOPE = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
 https://docs.google.com/feeds";

 Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential credential = new
 Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential(
     new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
     {
         Scopes = new[] { SCOPE }
     }.FromCertificate(certificate));


 bool success =
 credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result;

 var requestFactory = new Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestFactory("My
 Plastic SCM Service");
 requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer
 {0}", credential.Token.AccessToken));

 var s = new
 SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1"); s.RequestFactory =
 requestFactory; 
 return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that when adding the custom header you need:
"Authorization: Bearer {0}" <-- with a space between "Bearer" and "{0}"
Because:
"Authorization: Bearer{0}" <-- no space
will only get you an "unknown authorization header" Error 401 response