# Using Google SpreadsheetsService with Service Account

Tags: c#, .net, gdata, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to make some changes to existing Spreadsheet in Google Drive. I want to do that periodically, using scheduled process. Due to this I decided to use service account authentication, which is described here https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

The example is working fine and I can connect to the Plus API, however I need to connect to [Google Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/). The problem is that SpreadsheetsService does not seems to work with p12 files or Initializer class as DriveService does.

SpreadSheetsService has only 2 authentication methods which seems not to require to go by provided url - SetAuthenticationToken() and setUserCredentials(). There is no obvious way I can pass p12 file to the SpreadsheetService.

Did anyone solved this problem? I am okay with any "dirty" solution like decrypting p12 file (thought I don't think google provides password for this) or putting authentication headers from DriveService to SpreadsheetService. Did anyone solved this problem?

Or maybe there are 3rd parties libraries for C# that supports Spreadsheet API login via Service account?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I did not really get your comment. Service account can login with p12 file, but the C# code of SpreadsheetService just doesn't have a signature to accept anything else rather than login/password sequence which is unknown to me because it is a service account or AuthToken which is probably can be copied from DriveService, but again there no direct methods, afaik

Comment: I dont think that sheets api supports service accounts.  I have scanned though the documentation looks like only Oauth1, Oauth2 and client login are supported.    There also isnt any support in the client lib, i checked there to :)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to connect to Google Spreadsheet via Service account using Java or Python client library? I am okay even with that solution, though it is far away from perfect... And if there is a working example, that would be perfect!

Comment: if the api itself doesn't support it, using a different language won't help.

Comment: I see, this is bad. Okay, will try another approach. Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you check out google apps script - it can update spreadsheets via a time trigger. google apps script is server side java script that runs on google servers.

Comment: Sounds interesting, yet my application fetch data from a database and as far as I understand you cannot really get the data from google app (or have to share database credentials). One possible solution I can imagine is to separate the application in 2: my application will import csv file with the data into google drive and google app will update the real spreadsheet with the new data. What do you think, is it possible?

Comment: This might be helpful - http://blog.antontelle.com/post/sending-data-to-private-google-spreadsheet-via-service-account

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [How to use SpreadsheetsService authenticated by ServiceAccountCredential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185206/how-to-use-spreadsheetsservice-authenticated-by-serviceaccountcredential)

```
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
  new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccount) {
    Scopes = new[] {DriveService.Scope.Drive,"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"}
  }.FromCertificate(certificate)
);
bool success = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result;

....

SpreadsheetsService spreadsheetsService = new SpreadsheetsService(applicationName);
var requestFactory = new Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestFactory(applicationName);
  requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", credential.Token.AccessToken));
  spreadsheetsService.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
```