# Reusing Google API credentials in GData API

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-authentication

I am trying to make a web application is ASP.NET MVC 5 with which I can authenticate a user with a Google Account and then read data from his/her spreadsheets stored in Google Drive/Google Sheets.

I am using Google API to authenticate a user. After a user is successfully authenticated, I get the credentials back from Google in an object which is of type `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Web AuthResult.UserCredential`

I can then successfully create a service to list files from Drive using code similar to

`var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                        ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
                    });`

Now, I want to use GData API to read content from spreadsheets in Drive. For this to work, I need to have a `SpreadsheetsService` object and then set it's `RequestFactory` parameter to an instance of `GOAuth2RequestFactory` and this in turn needs OAuth2 parameters to be specified in an instance of class `OAuth2Parameters`.

How can I reuse the credentials obtained using the Google Api in GData API?

Comment: why not just create a SpreadsheetsService ? as long as the scopes used in creating your credential allows for both drive and SpreadsheetsService  there is no reason you cant create both.

Comment: I have created a `SpreadsheetsService`. I wouldn't want to start the authentication cycle again. I am looking for a way to use the Credentials from API in GData

Comment: Don't think I understand the problem creating a new service wont start authentication again you aready have result.credentials just use it in both.

Comment: @DaImTo The credentials that we had obtained from the Google API doesn't work with GData(since GData is an old API). Please see the image. I took a grab from Visual Studio http://pbrd.co/10uYsD7

Comment: How did you create these credentials? are they old open id credentials or something?  Can you show the code for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I am already doing the thing you want to do,

Code for how I passed the GData tokens 
[Issue with OAuth2 authentication with google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084133/issue-with-oauth2-authentication-with-google-spreadsheet/15152682#15152682)

i.e. I use a single OAuth2 access/refresh token set. Using the same tokens for both gdata calls & drive API calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that finally worked for me

```
public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
        {
            private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "randomstring.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                        ClientSecret = "shhhhhh!"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://docs.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

            public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
            {

                var user = controller.Session["user"];
                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = Guid.NewGuid();
                    controller.Session["user"] = user;
                }
                return user.ToString();
            }

            public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow { get { return flow; } }

        }
```

And then, in the controller, OAuth2 parameters were copied to GData

```
var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
                AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);
OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
                parameters.ClientId = "somestring.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                parameters.ClientSecret = "shhhhhh!";
                parameters.Scope = result.Credential.Token.Scope;
                parameters.AccessToken = result.Credential.Token.AccessToken;
                parameters.RefreshToken = result.Credential.Token.RefreshToken;

                GOAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuth2RequestFactory(null, "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1", parameters);

                SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");
                service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
```