# C# Google Spreadsheet Service with ServiceAccount Implementation

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api, service-accounts

What is "My App User Agent" in GDataRequestFactory. I have done mentioned above code but still not getting spreadsheets. I am not getting way to access spreadsheet data from Google Docs.

```
if (!File.Exists(keyFilePath))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An Error occurred - Key file does not exist");
        return null;
    }

    //Google Drive scopes Documentation:   https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://docs.google.com/feeds" };  // modify your app scripts     

    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    try
    {
        var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer =
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate);

        var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredentialInitializer);

        //if (!credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Result)
        //    throw new InvalidOperationException("Access token request failed.");

        credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None).Wait();

        var requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory("My App User Agent");
        requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + credential.Token.AccessToken);

        SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("CallLog");

        service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

        SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQue`enter code here`ry(); //do the job as you done it before
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.Query(query);
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Your code is not clear : SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQue`enter code here`ry(); What does that mean?

Comment: I set the OAuth2 this way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084133/issue-with-oauth2-authentication-with-google-spreadsheet/15152682#15152682   .. You can always try something like gridspree.io to check things.

Comment: Did you know what is the useragent? and what is the difference between useagent and applicationame?